# Setting up compass using the Yeoman angular-fullstack Gruntfile.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sass, gruntjs, compass

I have a super complex grunt file that has been generated from [Angular FullStack](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-angular-fullstack)

I want to add a gem called [Susy](https://rubygems.org/gems/susy) but it has a dependency of [compass](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass):

In the past i've been able to do this simply by adding: `require` to my grunt file

```
compass: {
  options: {
  require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have a similar compass code block in this Grunt file.

**QUESTION:**

**How can I add compass to my Gruntfile.js to watch my sass so that that I may use compass gems like Susy?**

Heres a link to [git](https://github.com/matthewharwood/harwood/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) (cuz I know it's long ) :c

```
// Generated on 2014-09-01 using generator-angular-fullstack 2.0.13
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var localConfig;
  try {
    localConfig = require('./server/config/local.env');
  } catch(e) {
    localConfig = {};
  }

  // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    injector: 'grunt-asset-injector',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control',
    pagespeed: 'grunt-pagespeed',
    responsive: 'grunt-responsive-images',
    autoshot: 'grunt-autoshot'
  });

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: 'server/app.js',
          debug: true
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: 'dist/server/app.js'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      injectJS: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'],
        tasks: ['injector:scripts']
      },
      injectCss: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
        ],
        tasks: ['injector:css']
      },
      mochaTest: {
        files: ['server/**/*.spec.js'],
        tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
      },
      injectSass: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['injector:sass']
      },
      sass: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      jade: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/*',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.jade'],
        tasks: ['jade']
      },
      coffee: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'
        ],
        tasks: ['newer:coffee', 'injector:scripts']
      },
      coffeeTest: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'
        ],
        tasks: ['karma']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
          '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      express: {
        files: [
          'server/**/*.{js,json}'
        ],
        tasks: ['express:dev', 'wait'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: [
          'server/**/*.js',
          '!server/**/*.spec.js'
        ]
      },
      serverTest: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc-spec'
        },
        src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
      },
      all: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
      ],
      test: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.openshift',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Debugging with node inspector
    'node-inspector': {
      custom: {
        options: {
          'web-host': 'localhost'
        }
      }
    },

    // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
    nodemon: {
      debug: {
        script: 'server/app.js',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
          env: {
            PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
          },
          callback: function (nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // opens browser on initial server start
            nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
              }, 500);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      target: {
        src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/',
        exclude: [/bootstrap-sass-official/, /bootstrap.js/, '/json3/', '/es5-shim/', /bootstrap.css/, /font-awesome.css/ ]
      }
    },
    // responsive: {
    //   dev: {
    //     options: {},
    //     sizes: [{
    //       width: 320,
    //       height: 240
    //     },{
    //       name: 'large',
    //       width: 640
    //     },{
    //       name: "large",
    //       width: 1024,
    //       suffix: "_x2",
    //       quality: 0.6
    //     }],
    //     files: [{
    //       expand: true,
    //       cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
    //       src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
    //       dest: 'dist/'
    //     }]
    //   }
    // },

    //autoshot the screen
    autoshot: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                path: './screenshots/',
                remote : {
                    files: [
                        { src: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>', dest: 'app.jpg'}
                    ]
                },
                viewport: ['320x480','480x320','384x640','640x384','602x963','963x602','600x960','960x600','800x1280','1280x800','768x1024','1024x768']
            }
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes 

    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public'
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        ],
        // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
        patterns: {
          js: [
            [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
    // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat',
          src: '*/**.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat'
        }]
      }
    },

    //allows pages speed results
    //
    pagespeed: {
      options: {
        nokey: true,
        url: "0.0.0.0:9000"
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          url: "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started",
          locale: "en_GB",
          strategy: "desktop",
          threshold: 80
        }
      },
      paths: {
        options: {
          paths: ["/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started", "/speed/docs/about"],
          locale: "en_GB",
          strategy: "desktop",
          threshold: 80
        }
      }
    },
    // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
    ngtemplates: {
      options: {
        // This should be the name of your apps angular module
        module: 'morningharwoodApp',
        htmlmin: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
        },
        usemin: 'app/app.js'
      },
      main: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
      },
      tmp: {
        cwd: '.tmp',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/fonts/**/*',
            'index.html'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            'package.json',
            'server/**/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
      }
    },

    buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: 'dist',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        connectCommits: false,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'heroku',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      },
      openshift: {
        options: {
          remote: 'openshift',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'coffee',
        'jade',
        'sass',
      ],
      test: [
        'coffee',
        'jade',
        'sass',
      ],
      debug: {
        tasks: [
          'nodemon',
          'node-inspector'
        ],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      },
      dist: [
        'coffee',
        'jade',
        'sass',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },

    mochaTest: {
      options: {
        reporter: 'spec'
      },
      src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
    },

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      },
      chrome: {
        options: {
          args: {
            browser: 'chrome'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    env: {
      test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      },
      prod: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      },
      all: localConfig
    },

    // Compiles Jade to html
    jade: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          data: {
            debug: false
          }
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          src: [
            '{app,components}/**/*.jade'
          ],
          dest: '.tmp',
          ext: '.html'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Compiles CoffeeScript to JavaScript
    coffee: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sourceRoot: ''
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'client',
          src: [
            '{app,components}/**/*.coffee',
            '!{app,components}/**/*.spec.coffee'
          ],
          dest: '.tmp',
          ext: '.js'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS
    sass: {
      server: {
        options: {
          loadPath: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
          ],
          compass: false
        },
        files: {
          '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    injector: {
      options: {

      },
      // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
              ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
            ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component scss into app.scss
      sass: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
            return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
          },
          starttag: '// injector',
          endtag: '// endinjector'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
            '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
          ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component css into index.html
      css: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  });

  // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
  grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
    grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

    var done = this.async();

    setTimeout(function () {
      grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
      done();
    }, 1500);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
    this.async();
  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    if (target === 'debug') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'injector:sass', 
        'concurrent:server',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concurrent:debug'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'env:all',
      'injector:sass', 
      'concurrent:server',
      'injector',
      'wiredep',
      'autoprefixer',
      'express:dev',
      'wait',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
    if (target === 'server') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mochaTest'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'client') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'injector:sass', 
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'autoprefixer',
        'karma',
        'autoshot'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'e2e') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'injector:sass', 
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'express:dev',
        'protractor'
      ]);
    }

    else grunt.task.run([
      'test:server',
      'test:client'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'injector:sass', 
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep',
    // 'responsive'
    'useminPrepare',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'pagespeed'
  ]);
  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);

};
```

UPDATE:

```
  // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems this Gruntfile uses the sass plugin and not the compass plugin. You need to install the [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) plugin, load it into the Gruntfile and add the task.

You may replace the `sass` task by your compass task. Do not forget to replace also the references into the watch task.

Comment: in the pass i've referenced my compass with this block (updated in code above) do all these options need to specified?  Is there anything this enormous block you see conflicting with compass instead of sass?  This seems liek such a headache

Comment: no it should work, tasks are separated in grunt. keep the paths as defined in the new file (ie. `<=%yeoman.client%>{app,components}`, replace the task reference in the watch task and it should do the job.

Comment: Bleh it just not gonna work like it traditionally would.  The whole globbing of of this generator is difffernt.  I just cant get it to work.  I'm kind of guessing and checking.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple. Just set the *compass* switch to **true**

> compass: **true**

```
// Compiles Sass to CSS
sass: {
  server: {
    options: {
      loadPath: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
      ],
      compass: true
    },
    files: {
      '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: sure but then how do I require susy?